# Occasional 'getaddrinfo: Name or service not known' error on Houston's APN#push call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Houston gem to send push notifications. `APN.push(notifications)` occasionally throws an error:

```
SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

The `push` method itself is called by sidekiq worker, if that matters.

Here's the output from the red RSpec test:

```
# /home/?/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/houston-2.2.4/lib/houston/connection.rb:36:in `initialize'
# /home/?/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/houston-2.2.4/lib/houston/connection.rb:36:in `new'
# /home/?/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/houston-2.2.4/lib/houston/connection.rb:36:in `open'
# /home/?/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/houston-2.2.4/lib/houston/connection.rb:19:in `open'
# /home/?/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/houston-2.2.4/lib/houston/client.rb:40:in `push'
# ./app/api/services/notification_service.rb:42:in `push'
# ./spec/services/notification_service_spec.rb:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# /home/?/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/generic/base.rb:16:in `cleaning'
# /home/?/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:98:in `cleaning'
# /home/?/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in cleaning'
# /home/?/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in `cleaning'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The problem occurs in all environments, causing part of notifications not being sent.

Where do I look to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby isn't able to resolve your provided hostname to an IP address. Since the hostname comes from a gem, I guess that part should be OK. Would you happen to have internet connection issues?

Comment: There might be, but they seem to happen too often, if this is the case. And I thought that sidekiq would retry performing the failed job, however some notifications are never delivered. Thank you for the answer!